# Can light (electromagnetic radiation) cause electromagnetic induction in a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Can light, as an electromagnetic wave, cause electromagnetic induction in a wire by passing near the wire? Does a moving electromagnetic wave cause a varying magnetic field in the region near the wire? Could light then be used to generate power by induction?

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary antenna you may see on a car has voltages and currents induced on it by very long wavelength "light" (radio waves) passing through it. To get to visible light, from a fundamental point of view the only difference is one of scale: an FM radio signal may have a wavelength of about 3 meters, but green light is around 550 nanometers. Use an antenna that's too long and the interior of it will basically not be able to contribute to the signal, since in the time it takes for a signal to get from the middle of the antenna to the outside the light wave's field will have already changed. So a suitable "antenna" for visible light would have to be molecule sized. Such things certainly exist. Consider beta-carotene: [image: Space-filling model of beta-carotene]

It consists of a central line of carbons connected by alternating single and double bonds (plus some stuff hanging off the ends and the sides). The alternating single and double bonds link up and form what's called a conjugated system. In the model above, you can essentially imagine a bunch of electrons that are free to "float" along the line of carbons in front of and behind your screen. These freely flowing electrons mean the molecule acts like a segment of conductive wire, and thus serves as an antenna for visible light. (The whole molecule is a couple nanometers long.) The molecules can pick up light of certain wavelengths, become excited, and then lose that energy as heat, thus being opaque to those wavelengths. At these sizes, quantum weirdness that I'm not going into starts to comes into play, but qualitatively it is the fact that beta-carotene (and related pigments) acts as an antenna for visible light that makes carrots orange and tomatoes red.

Speaking of plants, you may have guessed *why* they produce these antennas: molecules like beta-carotene can be used as receivers for light energy in photosynthesis. (We usually think of chlorophyll as collecting energy for photosynthesis, but other molecules like these can also contribute.) Similarly, that's why we need to consume these molecules (as vitamin A) for the health of our eyes: we *see* by putting these antennae in our retinas and attaching them to proteins that trigger neuronal activation when they absorb light.

P.S. Note that normal solar panels do *not* collect light energy in the same way as plants.

Answer (score 0):

Light rays are produced from electric fields of electrons flowing through a resistor.  On the other hand, light rays disturb electric fields of electrons in a solar cell to produce electric current.  Lights are concerned only with electric field.  Light rays cannot be used to disturb magnetic fields directly.  Radio waves (cell phone waves) are concerned only with magnetic field.  Radio waves cannot be used to disturb electric fields or light rays directly.

Answer (score -1):

Note that light (in one of its interpretations) is a Electromagnetic Wave. Now, there is a huge difference between the oscillating magnetic field in an EM wave and a magnetic field generated by a permanent magnet or an electromagnet.\

One of the differences is that magnitude of the magnetic field in an EM wave happens to be very small. In fact, the magnitude of the electric field is *c (speed of light)* times more than the magnetic field. It is very difficult to cause induction in a wire via the magnetic field of the EM Wave.

However, as explained already by @Alex, the electric field component of an EM wave can cause electrons to oscillate in a wire.